# CSS img:hover based on alt value

Tags: html, css, hover, image, alt

Can anyone tell me how I can apply some CSS to an `<img>` tag, based on its `alt`-attribute value?

e.g. I have images with an ALT value of DISAPPEAR

When hovered over, I want to set

```
img[DISAPPEAR]:hover
{
  display:none;
}
```

The code above doesn't seem to work though :(

Comment: Using `alt=DISAPPEAR` would probably conflict with the defined meaning of the `alt` attribute. People who do not see the image would see the word DISAPPEAR in its stead. Moreover, using `display: none` would cause the page to be reformatted. Consider using a `class` attribute and e.g. `visibility: hidden` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

```
img[alt="DISAPPEAR"]:hover
 {
 display:none;
 }
```

It works like this:
`selector[attribute="value"]`

Answer (score 0):

As CoderOfHonor said, you should use

```
img[alt="DISAPPEAR"]:hover
{
  display:none;
}
```

But to work in IE 8 or earlier you *should* have `<!DOCTYPE>`!

Comment: Regarding `doctype`, a declaration that triggers “Standards Mode” (where the CSS code works), such as `<!DOCTYPE html>`, is needed for all IE versions that support this CSS code in the first place.